# Unexpected SPACE character while in :Explore when hitting minus key (-) in Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

Whenever I hit the minus key (-) while in `:Explore` mode to `go up dir` there seems to be an extra `<SPACE>` character being added somehow.

The issue comes in when setting `<SPACE>` to map to `<PageDown>` which unexpectedly causes navigating up a directory to jump down a page. I've removed everything except `:map <Space> <PageDown>` from my `.vimrc` to try to narrow down the issue and to see if a plugin or setting was the cause. I'm using NVIM v0.4.2 installed using Homebrew.

I've used a similar setup on other machines in the past without this behavior and can't seem to pinpoint what I might be doing differently.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that sent me on a merry chase. I could be wrong, but I think there's a bug in netrw:

```
if !hasmapto('<Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir')       |nmap <buffer> <silent> <nowait> - <Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir |endif
```

See that space prior to `|endif`? I think that's getting sent along with the plugin command. I'll submit a patch, but in the meantime you could add this to your `.nvimrc` or `init.vim`:

```
nmap - <Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir
```

making sure there is no stray space at the end of that line!

Comment: Patch sent, hopefully it will show up in a future release. Can't remember the last time I sent a diff consisting of a single whitespace character!

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This was so misterious and annoying, since I use space as my leader key, so vim-which-key kept popping up for no reason. :D (Sadly it seems like the patch has still not been merged, or I don't know why it's showing up for me...)